# Changing of ASP.NET sqlprovider to sql server

Tags: asp.net

I want to store my data, user and userroles in sql server database rather than in a default database, one that is changed and when application is deployed.

How do I access ASP.NET configuration from our application to create or assign roles to the users?

Comment: Which MembershipProvider are you using? Don't you just create and assign roles through that?

Comment: check http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs